# Why action parameter cannot have same name as an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Say, I have an action

```
public ActionResult Details(MyModel details)
```

The details will always be null in this case, because the name matches method name. Rename it to something else - and it works fine.
To me, those are 2 separate things - one is url, another is POST data. 
Anyone seen MS explaining this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not null because the action is called `Details`. It is null because you have a property in the `MyModel` class that is called `Details`. So the default model binder doesn't know whether you want to assign the `Details` property of `MyModel` or `MyModel` directly. So either rename the action argument name or the name of the Details property in your model class.

Comment: I'd say it's null because the parameter name is 'details' - there's no Details property in MyDetails type.

Comment: @Eugene, I am unable to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a full example allowing to reproduce it? How do your view model, controller and view look like? How is this controller action invoked?

Comment: Hmm, I've just tried to reproduce it at home, and it works.. I'll double-check tomorrow at work.  Btw, it does stay null if parameter object has a property, named as a parameter itself - what causes this ?

Comment: Ok, I probably didn't have enough coffee yesterday :)  It did have the details property.  But still, why I can't have a property with same name as a parameter name ?

Comment: @Eugene, you can't because when you send a request parameter with `details.Foo=bar` the default model binder cannot know whether you want to set the `Foo` property of `MyModel` or you want to set the `Foo` property of the `Details` property of `MyModel`.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with MVC's convention over configuration.
This creates some restrictions.